# Программно выделить маркер на гугл карте

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как полноценно программно выделить маркер на гугл карте, чтобы появилось и инфо-окно и выезжающий снизу справа MapToolbar? 
Делаю вот так, инфо-окно нормально работает, а MapToolbar снизу справа не выезжает, а срабатывает только когда непосредственно пальцем по маркеру кликнешь по экрану..

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 2):

Map Toolbar нельзя сделать видимым программно на интерактивной карте (только на статичной где один маркер). Ведь у Вас может быть несколько маркеров на экране, а построение пути показывается в одном месте.

Вот ишью https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825834

Comment: А Вы не знаете, выделение с маркера можно снять программно? marker.hideInfoWindow(); тоже не снимает выделение, а просто скрывает инфо-окно..